# How do I speed up my old Ubuntu computer?

Tags: unity-2d

My computer is really slow.  Slow enough that each time the page updates, it updates in a "wave" from top to bottom, which takes about a second.  **I want to keep Ubuntu and Unity 2D,** but I just need a way to get my computer to run faster, because if it continues, it just can't be productive.  Help is appreciated.

PS:  No, I am not interested in Xubuntu

Comment: Try Xubuntu or Lubuntu instead.

Comment: @Mizuki Oshiro It is a Dell Dimension 2400 with a Pentium 4 at 768MB and somewhere above 2GHz.  It can't run 3D desktop environments, by the way.

Comment: Is the system very slow otherwise? For instance, how long does it take to launch libreoffice? Because if the graphics is slow, then the system will feel slow even if it really isn't. And slow graphics can be due to a bad driver. If you look in system monitor, is it under heavy load?

Comment: What graphic card does it have and how much memory is there on it? You need a graphic card with more memory.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad LibreOffice takes somewhere in the middle of apps.  It took about 10 seconds to start.  Others, like the Ubuntu Software Center, takes like 15 seconds.  Loading pages and scrolling is slow and laggy, though.

Comment: @grahammechanical I don't know how to change my graphics card.  And by the way, it's an "integrated Intel 3D Extreme Graphics" card.

Comment: on old computers and also on new ones, it helps a lot to change your classic HD for a SSD, the difference is huge,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a link to the technical specifications of your machine.

[Dell 2400 specs](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim2400/en/sm_en/specs.htm)

Notice that it has integrated graphics/video which uses a maximum of 64MB of system RAM. This is causing the slowdown in screen re-drawing. In my opinion.

The machine only has PCI slots, so if you buy a new graphic card make sure that it is PCI and not PCI-E as it will not fit in the machine.

The answer to your problem is either:

1. Buy a PCI graphic card with as much memory as possible. They will be hard to find. I have just checked the shop where I purchased the parts for my machine and they had only 1 PCI graphic card out of 90 products. The rest were PCI-E.
2. Put the cost of a new graphic card towards the cost of a new computer; or
3. Use another version of Ubuntu that does not run Unity.

Sorry, if this is not to your liking. It is the answer.

Comment: Ok.  I guess I follow along with that.  I'm getting a replacement next year anyways.

Answer (score 1):

you can try elementary Os, it is very light, but if you still have problems I would try to LMDE. Tuquito Linux, Crunchbang, linux Austrumi and Elive 2.0 (in that order for me xD). Or get off the last-minimal ubuntu cd and I'll make to taste :P

---

Sorry for the bad english..

Answer (score 0):

I would give [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) (which uses the [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) desktop environment) a try.

Comment: Why? Unity 2D runs well, and that's what he wants to use.